# If p prime and p∣ab , then p∣a or p∣b

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers

Proposition: if a and b are integers, p is prime and p|ab then p|a or p|b

I'm getting started on math proofs, I want to know how can I write a simple valid proof of this without using the Bézout's identity, and making it as easier as posible.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: use the unique prime factorization

Comment: This question has been answered a few times, such as here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2668515/prove-if-p-is-prime-and-p-%E2%88%A3-ab-then-p-%E2%88%A3-a-or-p-%E2%88%A3-b. It is worth doing a quick search before posting questions, or, if your question is different, try to make it really clear how your question is different. Your question seems to be a simple statement of Euclid's lemma as it is currently written.

Comment: Use search, this question certainly has an answer here. For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162373/if-prime-p-mid-ab-then-p-mid-a-or-p-mid-b-euclids-lemma. Different answers using different techniques.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove: if p is prime and p ∣ ab, then p ∣ a or p ∣ b.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2668515/prove-if-p-is-prime-and-p-%e2%88%a3-ab-then-p-%e2%88%a3-a-or-p-%e2%88%a3-b)

Comment: @RedFive OP wanted the proof without Bezout’s lemma, so your link is not quite what fits here.

Comment: Is the Bezout lemma the same as Euclid's lemma?

Comment: @RedFive [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_identity).

Comment: Thanks @Aig - I didn't think so, but it has been a while since I studied number theory in proper depth.

Comment: If you don't want to use Bezout's lemma, you can use an inductive argument. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma